# TextBlock Style Setter for the Cursor property

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I want to change cursor style when mouse is over the WPF TextBlock.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="HoverBox">
     <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />   
           </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The problem is that `<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />` doesn't work.

But this Setter works fine  `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />`

Also I need to use **underlying** font style. How I can do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm guessing that you're attempting to emulate a `Hyperlink`, have you considered just using the `Hyperlink` class (control)?

Comment: This code works fine for me...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque  Yes. It seems that @ H. B. is right. I use Expression Dark theme and it seems a precedence problem appears.

Comment: Have you solved it, @ClarkKent?

Comment: @MadDeveloper No I did not I used another theme...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have a [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) problem? e.g. when you set the cursor on the styled control the trigger will not have enough precedence to change the value.

*(If i apply this style to a `TextBlock` which only has its `Text` set it works just fine)*